# How to find out who is logged into my iis7/sharepoint website?

Tags: iis-7, sharepoint-2010, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a Sharepoint2010/II7/winserver2008r2 site.

And I would like to limit the number of logins for 1 individual user to 3.

e.g.

```
user x logs into site from computer 1, accept
user x logs into site from computer 2, accept
user x logs into site from computer 3, accept
user x logs into site from computer 4, fail.
```

Comment: Why do you care? Also, in the web world, what is a "login"?

Comment: I want to limit 1 individual user to 3 login sessions.
it could prevent a large scale DoS.

Comment: Isn't that more a job for a firewall than a job for your application?

Comment: a firewall will not know the users identity. I need to look for a way to capture login attempts

Comment: Again, I recommend that  you re-evaluate this requirement. "Login" and "sessions" mean something quite different for a web application than for a classic desktop application. Among other things, you need to ask yourself whether a second open tab constitutes a second login. Same with a second window.

Comment: Typically this is handled by the browsers internally.
If you open up your browser and login and open 10 tabs, you have 1 login.
If you open up IE and FF you have 2 logins.

Comment: Yeah, that's my point. So, what, exactly, do you want to restrict? That's what you have to decide.

Comment: As mentioned above, using SharePoint and IIS to prevent a DoS might not be the best approach. You should use software that's purpose built to do that. That being said, you could create a custom HTTP module that keeps track of separate user sessions and limits them to some number that you decide.

Comment: You also wont know (for sure) if a previous "login" has terminated or still active, so the count will increase and always hit 4 - fail.